# Safely Handling Concurrent Memcache save in AppEngine

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, memcached

I have in my application a lot of threads trying to put the same key in memcache. What I need to do is, once a thread managed to put that key then no other thread should put that key again.

I've come across some mechanisms provided by memCache, like `putIFUnTouched` which I was trying to use like this:

```
IdentifiableValue value = memCache.getIdentifiable("item_id");
mc.putIfUnTouched("item_id", null, "user_id");
```

But it gives me this Exception: `oldValue mustn't be null`.

I also found `CAS` and I'm now confused which one of those I need to use in such situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
memCache.put("key", "object", Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(10000), MemcacheService.SetPolicy.ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT);
```